# d3 javascript naming or referring to groups

Tags: javascript, d3.js, reference, naming

I am trying to reference different groups in d3 in order to change colours of the contents inside each of the groups for the function onHover. For example I have two groups both consisting of rectangles. I want to select one group and make them all one colour and I want to select the other group and make them a different colour.

Is there a way to reference each group and perform specific demands?

such that:

```
    var group1 = canvas.append("group1: g"); //contains rects
    var group2 = canvas.append("group2: g"); //contains rects


    d3.select("group1").style() //change colour
```

Comment: what is the group you mean?

Comment: by group i mean the "g". I was wondering if i can name this at all i.e. "name1: g", so that i can call it in d3 and change specific elements of that group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give IDs or classes to the `g` elements and select accordingly:

```
canvas.append("g").attr("id", "foo");
canvas.append("g").attr("class", "bar");

canvas.selectAll("g#foo");
canvas.selectAll("g.bar");
```